# dot operator and static keyword in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, static, operator-keyword

Hello fellow programmers. 
I have a question about static and the dot operator using this example in Java.

So I have this class variable declaration of an ArrayList inside my Inventory class.

```
static List<Multimedia> list = new ArrayList<Multimedia>();
```

If I choose to use the add method of the ArrayList in the method, should I write the method call like this: `Inventory.list.add(Object o)` or should I use `list.add(Object o)`. Do they mean the same thing? If they are not, which method call should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside the class you have to access it via the class name (but it depends on the access modifier i.e **private** cannot be accessed outside the class), inside the class you could use either of them.

Answer (score 5):

from class both are same,

Use

```
Inventory.list.add(Object o )
```

It will keep telling you  that its a static field in code

Comment: Code conventions suggest calling using the class name still, but that's up to you.

Comment: And yes as @AVD suggested its nice to hide the list and provide handle to it using methods

Answer (score 4):

You can't access the `list` in other packages so it would be better to create private *list* and expose it via public *wrapper* methods.

```
private static List<Multimedia> list = new ArrayList<Multimedia>();

public static void addMultimedia(Multimedia media){
   list.add(media);
}
public static List<Multimedia> getList(){
  return list;
}
```

To add `Multimedia` object:

```
Inventory.addMultimedia(new Multimedia());
//or
Inventory.getList().add(new Multimedia());
```

Answer (score 1):

Definately you should use `Inventory.list.add(Object o )` because static fields are at class level i.e. shared among objects of that class.

Comment: Thanks so much for the replies! I will use the code convention as suggest using Classname. I love your suggestion AVD. That's a good idea :)